# Unicode predicate with like clause ( N'%өө%' )returns all rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I use following condition in SQL Query

> [FieldName] like N'%өө%'

here the field name can be replaced with any column in any table you have..collation is `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`

I tested on SQLServer express,SQLServer 2012,2016 for any type of field.

Any ideas on why this is happening ?

Can anybody please confirm if it is same for you?

**below is a simple repro:**

```
create table dbo.test111
(
id int
)

insert into dbo.test111
select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by (Select null))
from
sys.objects s
cross join
sys.objects s1

select * from dbo.test111 where id like
 N'%өө%'
```

Comment: What is this character `өө` and does every record have one of them?

Comment: What collation is your db using?

Comment: @Filburt I think you're on to something...so you are saying that `өө` is collating to some other (common) character?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It's just the first thing to ask if comparing character data.

Comment: Good question,i was able to repro this

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: you can replace field name with any column name to test

Comment: Datbase collation is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS and it is even working for numerical fields.

Comment: Reproduced on SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS. As expected only NULLs aren't selected.

Comment: Related: https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/171331/5273

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case, you need to use a collation for [Supplementary Characters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/collation-and-unicode-support#Supplementary_Characters)

```
[FieldName] like N'%өө%' collate Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC
```

This should yield the expected result.

Explore the demo and see that removing the collation causes all records to be returned.

## Demo

Comment: Does it mean If I convert my database default collation to Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC then I wouldn't have to use collation every time?

Comment: Yes, if you want to cater for this on database level you should change your db collation. (No need however to change your *server* default collation)

Comment: @Filburt Thank you for your answer. The only thing I cannot understand: I read about Supplementary Characters, they write "characters with codepoint values larger than 0xFFFF require two consecutive 16-bit words. These characters are called supplementary characters, and the two consecutive 16-bit words are called surrogate pairs". It's ok, but the OP character has a codepoint 1257 (4E9) that is **less** than EEEE, so how did you figured out it was supplementary?

Comment: @THEn  >>>Does it mean If I convert my database default collation to Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC then I wouldn't have to use collation every time?<<< You should not change your db collation. The problems that you''ll have in the case your db collation is different from server collation will be greater than you think. You'll have to specify the collation any time you create temporary tables that are in join or do other comparisons with your db tables. I advice you to change only the necessary FIELDS collation

Comment: @sepupic I admit that I didn't check the codepoint and merely guessed by the looks. And I think I can learn a lot more from the link [Heinzi provided in his comment](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/171331/5273).

Comment: @Filburt Thank you again for the new link provided, I did not see it, I'm going to read it